# Change User-Agent

Tags: ios, swift, user-agent, nsurlrequest

How can I change in my WebView the default string of User-Agent?

```
@IBOutlet weak var myWbView: UIWebView!
let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://http://web-example")
let myURLRequest:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
myWbView.loadRequest(myURLRequest)
```

Comment: When I Google e.g. `WebView change useragent swift` I seem to be getting a lot of results?

Comment: There are a lot of results and I don't understand what is the result for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to set User-Agent HTTP header for your request that is going to be used for Web-view loading,

```
let userAgent = "Custom User Agent";
let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://http://web-example")
let myURLRequest:NSURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
myWbView.loadRequest(myURLRequest)    
myURLRequest.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
```

If you want to set User-Agent for all requests in your app, see this question
[How can I set the "User-Agent" header of a UIWebView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219997/how-can-i-set-the-user-agent-header-of-a-uiwebview-in-swift)

Comment: @Alexander Tkachenko your code is not usable, but the link before was right for me, so thank you

Comment: It seems that UIWebView does not actually let you override the user agent in this way.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20632315/1148843

Comment: Not useable! The custom user Agent is always be overridden with the default. You can test the "allHTTPHeaderFields" in UIWebViewDelegate-Method: shouldStartLoadWith after the "webView.loadRequest" call.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is very easy. For that, you should use `NSMutableURLRequest`, initialize it with the `NSURL`, and set any user agent value using method `setValue:ForHTTPHeaderField:`, where field would be `User-Agent`, load it on the web view. That's it! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2

You always can override global UserAgent field, it is resolve your problem:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent" : "Custom UserAgent)"])
```