# How can I get the “User-Agent” of a UIWebView in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I need to modify the useragent for some requests, and therefore I would either need to get it first, or append something to it. What's the best way of doing this? Do you have to use a webview to do it, or are there other ways?

what i trying :

```
var  userAgent = ""
    if UIWebView().stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent") != nil{
        userAgent  =  userAgent  + " Custom-Agent"
    }
    print(userAgent)
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent" : userAgent])
```

Comment: `UIWebView` is deprecated, use `WKWebView` in newer projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get user agent

```
var webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect.zero)
var secretAgent: String? = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent")
```

[Change User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889970/change-user-agent)

Comment: Doesn't seem like this got anything, had to change some code as well as it was giving warnings and errors.

Comment: Added to question.

Comment: @JDoe what is the error ? would you check the link that i was suggest

Comment: it doesnt get any ua, its empty, all the string has is "Custom-Agent", and ur link just shows how to set the ua, i already know how to do that

Comment: @JDoe i updated my answer would you check this please