# Force React-Native webview to load url as Mobile?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-webview

In java with android studio I achieve this by adding this code:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

but I don't know how to do this in React-Native, I try some css style but nothing did the trick.

here is my webview in React:

```
<WebView
  ref="WebView"
  scalesPageToFit={true}
  onLoadStart={this.onLoadStart}
  onLoadEnd={this.onLoadEnd}
  source = {{ uri:this.props.navigation.getParam('main_url', 
  'https://xxxx.xxx/')}}
  style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent',width: '100%'}}
/>:null}
```

Comment: The WebView shows the website though, right? Just not in a mobile layout?

Comment: yes, it show the desktop version, and works ok, but we need to load the mobilie version

Comment: @JonTargaryen set user-agent. It will load it as mobile.

Comment: What device are you using to test this? When you open that website in that device's browser, do you see the mobile version?

Comment: Yes we see mobile version on the device if we use chrome for example...

Comment: @SanyamJain cant you tell me what user agent use to load mobile versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use user-agent.

Note: This used to only work in Android. For iOS, you could use this link [Change User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889970/change-user-agent)
Now it seems to work on both iOS and android

```js
<Webview
  userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Pixel 2 XL Build/OPD1.170816.004) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3714.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from Sanyam's comment, you need to set user-agent for it to load as mobile:

```
<WebView
    userAgent={DeviceInfo.getUserAgent() + " - MYAPPNAME - android "}
    {...otherProps}
/>
```